# File "C:/Users/PDJ/PycharmProjects/pythonProject_snow/main.py", line 19, in <module> face = faces[0] IndexError

Tags: python, opencv3.0

```
import cv2,dlib, sys
import  numpy as np

scaler = 0.3

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read() # 프레임 단위로 읽기
    if not ret:
        break

    img = cv2.resize(img, (int(img.shape[1]*scaler), int(img.shape[0]*scaler)))

    faces = detector(img)
    face = faces[0]

    img = cv2.rectangle(img, pt1=(face.left(),face.top(),), pt2=(face.right(),face.bottom()),color=(255,255,255),thickness=2,
                        lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(1) #딜레이를 걸어주는 함수
```

i tried to find face with webcam but i couldn't do because of above that

Answer (score 1):

`detector(img)` is not guaranteed to always return a face, if the camera has not focused yet or if the face is difficult to see. Check whether the list is non-empty first:

```
if faces:
  face = faces[0]

  img = cv2.rectangle(img, pt1=(face.left(),face.top(),), pt2=(face.right(),face.bottom()),color=(255,255,255),thickness=2,
                    lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

  cv2.imshow('img',img)
  cv2.waitKey(1) #딜레이를 걸어주는 함수
```

You may wish to also check that the size of the image after resizing makes sense -- in the dimensions `int(img.shape[1]*scaler), int(img.shape[0]*scaler)`, it looks like the image may be scaled out of proportion based on the order of `shape[1]` and `shape[0]`.

Comment: oh thank you it's working but actually i want to find a face with webcam but it only work on video file when i insert into VideoCapture(0), there isn't any response